# Get the first number value from a descendant inside a table

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to a way to get the first number value present inside a table (and respective tbody), but it needs to be able to find the value the first number, and ignores all the tags it comes accross until it reaches the number value.

```
<table id="TableID">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            4031007
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            whatever
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in the above example, we would try to find 4031007, which is inside a `<span>`, but it could've been a `<div>` or something else. I need this without using JQuery. Any help?

Comment: Split the `textContet` of the `table` by spaces, and iterate the resulted array until a number is found.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the plain old way: make a recursive function that will return text of the first node which has a text content:

```
function findFirstNumber(node) {
    // If this is a text node, return its contents. Trim it because there is
    // whitespace between the elements that should be ignored
    if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
        return node.textContent.trim();

    // Iterate over all child nodes and finde the first one that has text in it
    for (var child = node.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        var content = firstText(child);
        if (content && isNumber(content))
            return content;
    }

    // No text found
    return '';
}

function isNumber(value) {
    return !!isNaN(value);
}

console.log(findFirstNumber(document.getElementById('TableID')));
```

I used the [mdn page about Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node#Browse_all_child_nodes) to find out how to do this.

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLxuka1L/1/) (open your console)

Comment: To check if it's a number rather than a string just use !isNaN(content). If this returns false then carrying on iterating.

Answer (score 0):

How about a fancy find function that accepts regular expressions.

```
function findRegExp(start, reg, mod) {
    if (! (reg && start)) return this;

    return [].slice.call(start.querySelectorAll('*')).filter(function(elem) {
        if (typeof reg == 'string') 
            reg = new RegExp(reg, mod ? mod : '');

        var clone = elem.cloneNode(true),
            child = clone.children;

        for (var i=child.length; i--;) 
            clone.removeChild(child[i]);

        var txt = clone.textContent.trim();

        return reg.test(txt);
    });
}
```

to be used like

```
var elems = findRegExp(document.getElementById('TableID'), /^\d+$/);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wmpz2gzs/1/)

and the jQuery version

```
$.fn.findRegExp = function(reg, mod) {
    if (!reg) return this;
    return this.find('*').addBack().filter(function() {
        if (typeof reg == 'string') 
            reg = new RegExp(reg, mod ? mod : '');
        var c = $(this).clone();
        c.children().remove();
        var txt = $.trim(c.text());

        return reg.test(txt);
    });
}
```

Then you can search for an element containing only numbers

```
$('#TableID').findRegExp(/^\d+$/);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wmpz2gzs/)